# DatePicker no cambia Mes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, datepicker

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema al inicializar un date picker, este cambia el dia, el año sin embargo el mes no. Hoy por ejemplo 03-06-2021 selecciono la fecha pero en app me aparece 03-05-2021. Dejo codigo de mi date picker por si me pudieran ayudar.

```
class DatePickerFragment(val listener: (day:Int, month:Int, year:Int)-> Unit):DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {



override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    listener(dayOfMonth, month, year)
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val day =  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    val picker = DatePickerDialog(activity as Context, R.style.datePickerTheme, this, year, month, day )
    picker.datePicker.maxDate = c.timeInMillis
    picker.datePicker.minDate = c.timeInMillis
    return picker
}
```

}

```
private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
    val datePicker = DatePickerFragment { day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year) }
    datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")
}


fun onDateSelected(day:Int, month:Int, year:Int){
    fecha.setText("$day$month$year")

}
```

Comment: No necesitas crear tu propio datePicker, este componente ya existe y seguramente lo tienes en tus dependencias porque es parte de material design.  [Esta](https://material.io/components/date-pickers) es la guía para implementarlo.

Comment: Independientemente de la respuesta que te dieron, recuerda que el mes inicia en 0 por lo que debes modificarlo quedando así: `val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1`

Comment: Ambos aporte me sirvieron, muchisimas gracias =)